# ASP.NET model: Why isn't the product image displaying in my cart view?

Tags: asp.net, model

I don't know how to show an image from my folders to the view.

I have a ProductModel where i have created a list of some properties to be displayed to the product page. On the product page there is a buy now option which adds the selected product to my cart(view). All the details of the selected product are supposed to be displayed in the cart and it is working properly except it isn't showing the image of the product.
These are codes of ProductModel.cs:

```
new Product {
                    Id = "p01",
                    Name = "Relaxed Fit Printed hoodie",
                    Photo = @"C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\CA2\CA2\Images\Men\hoodie1men.jpg",
                    Price = 2299,
            }
```

And these are codes from Cart View:

```
@foreach (Item item in (List<Item>)Session["cart"])
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("Remove", "Cart", new { id = item.Product.Id })">Remove</a></td>
                <td>@item.Product.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Product.Name</td>
                <td><img src="~/Content/Images/@item.Product.Photo" width="60" /> </td>
                <td>@item.Product.Price</td>
                <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                <td>@(item.Product.Price*item.Quantity)</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: What's your controller's code? How you pass the model to the view ?